# I cannot connect my Spring boot JPA to Postgresql DB, but psql is accessible

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I'm trying to get my JPA to connect to my *Postgresql DB*, but somehow it just tell me it can't without more details, and my *psql* could connect it without problem. So there must have something misconfigured or missed. Please point it(them) out for me.

POM.xml
[image]

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test1234

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

Stack trace

```
2022-02-07 11:28:04.202  WARN 5476 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    ...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:238) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:215) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    ... 116 common frames omitted
```

PSQL

[image]

======= Update =======

Tried this little example from internet on same IDE and environment, I got true from DB. Look like my IDE didn't get blocked or sandboxed by my Comodo IS. And my OS is win10.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test", "test", "test1234");
            
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT 1=1");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Rsp: " + rs.getBoolean(1));
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
            if(rs != null)
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {  }
            
            if(stmt != null)
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {  }
            
            if(conn != null)
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {  }
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add `-h 127.0.0.1` to your psql.  Otherwise you are not testing the same thing, one uses TCP and the other a local socket.

Comment: @jjanes Just tried it and it is working as same as above. So I think it is not related to my DB privileges.

Comment: Based on the error, I would think Java is running in some sort of sandbox that cannot access the network, or some other app-specific security feature is kicking in.  What is your OS?  Can you write a very simple Java program to connect using just JDBC?

Comment: @jjanes I have added the test code that I used and my result in my question. Feel free to have a look.

Comment: And not sure this is related, but this spring boot project is generated from Spring Initializr website.